# problem with postgresql and .net entity framework for adding views and tables

Tags: .net, postgresql, entity-framework

I dont know anyone here worked with postgressql and entity framework,its a big pain!you can not do it like sql,update model from database,you will get unexpected errors like there is no foreign key,i should manually add it thought .xml view of my model,which takes hours to add multiple views,or i should forget entityframework and use ADO to retrive data,any same experience? any help will be appreciated

Comment: I regularly use EF with PostgreSQL. If you are mapping to an existing schema then I would recommend using `EntityTypeConfiguration` declarations for your entities rather than trying to use the designers and auto-generation. These are straight-forward blocks of code, and EF can work out the trivial bits by convention. (just map the Keys, relationships, and any naming/type deviations between your entity and table/view) I'm not a fan of code generation/designers as there's commonly real world cases that don't fit their patterns.

Comment: @StevePy is there any example?thanks

Comment: You can find a number of examples of EntityTypeConfiguration and modelBuilder config on the web, or search through my answers to various other questions as I tend to put in quite a few suggested configurations for utilizing navigation properties and the like, and I typically use EntityTypeConfiguration. i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50494020/missing-id-on-insert-of-one-to-one-or-zero-with-entity-framework/50499342#50499342

Comment: i created a new test application,installed all entityframework and npgsql package,added a edmx file manually and created my class there,but i get System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException: 'Unable to load the specified metadata resource.' error

Comment: Model.context.tt and model.tt  are the files i should add class and mapping manually?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help much with EF Core, I use EF6, though I'd probably consider trying to configure a couple table-entity relationships manually to determine what options work. A lot will hinge on what has been implemented in the npgsql packages.

Comment: Im working with EF6 not core,i would appreciate if you tell me where exactly i should add class(mapped class) and DbContext'

Comment: The EntityTypeConfiguration definitions can be located anywhere, but I typically put them in a /Configuration folder beneath the entity class location. To register them with the DbContext, override OnModelCreating in the DbContext and add `modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly(typeof(MyDbContext).Assembly);` assuming the entity configurations are in the same assembly as your DbContext.